# Unable to use dot(.) in orchestration project name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, biztalk

I am getting below error if I am including dot(.) in orchestration project name in visual studio though required dll is added in references. Its allowing me to keep project name as ENTITYSRCDESTOrchestrations but not allowing ENTITY.SRC.DEST.Orchestrations.

> **Error:**
> Severity: Error
> Code: CS0234
> Description: The type or namespace name 'Common_Orchestrations' does not exist in the namespace 'Entity.SRC.PS' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> Project: ENTITY.SRC.DEST.Orchestrations
> File: I:\ENTITY.SRC.DEST\ENTITY.SRC.DEST.Orchestrations\obj\Release\BizTalk\XLang\File1.cs
> Line: 9
> Suppression State: Active

Comment: If you rename a project, you will also have to change any references to it also.

Comment: Find `Common_Orchestrations` and see what's the namespace for it. Then go to `File1.cs` line 9 and change the namespace to the new namespace. The error is pretty clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you are missing the reference of your project. This error is clearly stating "missing an assembly reference"
Please refer to Microsoft Doc to get the resolution,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/core/build-errors-in-the-task-list#compiler-asks-if-you-are-missing-an-assembly-reference